# Woocommerce update order_comments after placed order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

custom field needs to be appended to Order notes when order is placed. I can update the Company and Append the number to the end using

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_company', $_companyName );
```

on the order details page in admin, the field under Shipping details called

"Customer Provided Note" is called "order_comments" on the checkout page.

On the order details page it is referred to as "excerpt" as well as "post_excerpt".
If I use `update_post_meta( $order_id, 'post_excerpt', $_urn );`
 the field is not updated. I have also tried with excerpt and order_comments and I cannot update this field.

Any Ideas?

Comment: update_post_meta( $order_id, 'post_excerpt', $_urn ); does create a custom field but I need to update the order_comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Customer Provided Note" is stored as the `post_excerpt` on the `order` post_type backing the `WC_Order`. To update it you can use the standard WordPress Codex, or the [`wc_update_order()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_update_order.html) function (which is effectively a front end to the WordPress Codex, but probably the right way to go).

```
// specify the order_id so WooCommerce knows which to update
$order_data = array(
    'order_id' => $order_id,
    'customer_note' => 'The customer note.'
);
// update the customer_note on the order
wc_update_order( $order_data );
```

Comment: thanks for the input, much appreciated. this unfortunately updates Order Notes and I need Customer Provider Note updated, located under the shipping details

Comment: @RobertWilde Sorry, I misread your question. Changed the answer to show how to update the correct value.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why that was so hard to find